# Unsure on proper use of Serial Port Data Received Event

Tags: vb.net, excel, serial-port, vsto

I'm working on a VSTO add-in for Excel 2013 in VB.NET that will help me interface with an instrument via a serial connection.  I currently have the COM connection set up correctly and it will allow me to send and receive one command at a time.  I'd like to set it up so that I can push one button and have it collect two separate readings in different worksheet cells.  Using the code below, the tools work great to collect a single reading, but when I enable the code to send a second command to the instrument the Data Received event stops working entirely until I send another single read command.  I know that the instrument received and processed the second command, but it never appears in excel.  Could anyone help with a way to modify this code?

```
Private Sub mySerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    'Handles serial port data received events
    UpdateFormDeligate1 = New UpdateFormDeligate(AddressOf UpdateDisplay)

    Dim n As Integer = mySerialPort.BytesToRead 'find number of bytes in buff
    comBuffer = New Byte(n - 1) {} 're-dimension storage buffer (n - 1)
    mySerialPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, n) 'read data from the buffer

    comBuffer2 = mySerialPort.ReadTo(vbCr)

    Me.Invoke(UpdateFormDeligate1) 'call the deligate
    mySerialPort.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub Invoke(updateFormDeligate1 As UpdateFormDeligate)
    lblReading.Label = processReading() 'write to a Current Reading lable on the ribbon

    Dim myApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim currentCell = myApp.ActiveCell
    currentCell.Value = processReading() 'write data in the excel active cell

    Try
        advanceCell()
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If measureNo = 2 Then 'this case is selected when I want to read 2 measurements with a single button push
        cmdSent = 2
        sendCommand(measureCmd)

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDisplay()

End Sub
```

Note that I did not include my sendCommand sub because this is a simple .write command to the instrument that appears to be working correctly in all cases.  I'd much appreciate any help anyone could provide as I'm pretty new to using data received events.

Comment: Lots of bugs, the most severe one is calling Close() inside the event handler.  That ends the show after the first command.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I added that close to see if it mattered if I opened the serial port again after the first write.  There is a routine in the write command that opens the serial port if it is closed.  It doesn't seem to matter if I keep the port open to try to do two write/reads or if I closed it then opened it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried to isolate only the relevant the part of the script that was having an issue and I created a completely new toolbar for testing.  Below is the full code for this new toolbar that contains one connect/measure button and a label that displays the status/result.  I tried to comment the code to make it readable, hopefully this helps.

This new toolbar does appear to be working correctly.  I'm still a little unsure on my correct usage of the DataReceived event handler in conjunction with the Invoke method (which Visual Studio slightly changed for use with Excel2013).  Could anyone please provide comment as to whether I'm still using these events in an unclear way and provide a suggestion on how I may make it better?

Thanks again in advance for any help.  I really appreciate it.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Measure2x_COM
Dim mySerialPort As New SerialPort
Dim CMD As String = "M" & vbCr 'statement telling instrument to measure
Dim measureNo As Integer = 0 'counts the number of measure commands sent to the instrument

Private Delegate Sub UpdateFormDeligate()
Private UpdateFormDeligate1 As UpdateFormDeligate

Dim sngReading As Single 'this is the reading received from the instrument as a single data type

Private Sub setupConnectCOM()
    'Open COM and send measure command - this part works correctly
    'first, check if serial port is open
    If mySerialPort.IsOpen Then 'send measure command
        mySerialPort.Write(CMD) 'the instrument will generally take 15.1 sec to perform a measurement before sending the result back
    Else
        'if serial port is not open, set it up, then open, then send command
        'Setup COM --this part works correctly
        With mySerialPort
            .PortName = "COM3"
            .BaudRate = 1200
            .DataBits = 7
            .Parity = Parity.None
            .StopBits = StopBits.Two
            .Handshake = Handshake.None
            .ReadTimeout = 16000
        End With

        Try
            mySerialPort.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub 'exit sub if the connection fails
        End Try
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(200) 'wait 0.2 sec for port to open

        mySerialPort.Write(CMD) 'send measure command after serial port is open

    End If
    measureNo = 1
    lblResult.Label = "Measuring"
End Sub

Private Sub Measure2x_COM_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler mySerialPort.DataReceived, AddressOf mySerialPort_DataReceived

End Sub

Private Sub mySerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    'Handles serial port data received events
    UpdateFormDeligate1 = New UpdateFormDeligate(AddressOf UpdateDisplay)

    'Read data as it comes back from serial port
    'I had to do this in two steps because it, for some reason needs to read
    'the +/- symbol as a Byte, then needs to read the ASCII measurement number
    'the third part concatenates the data and converts it to a single type

    'part 1 - read +/- symbol
    Dim comBuffer As Byte()
    Dim n As Integer = mySerialPort.BytesToRead 'find number of bytes in buff
    comBuffer = New Byte(n - 1) {} 're-dimension storage buffer (n - 1)
    mySerialPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, n) 'read data from the buffer

    'part 2 - read ASCII measurement number
    Dim comBuffer2 As String
    comBuffer2 = mySerialPort.ReadTo(vbCr)

    'part 3 - concatenate read data and convert to single type
    Dim txtReading As String = Nothing
    txtReading = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(comBuffer) & CStr(CInt(comBuffer2) / 10)
    sngReading = CSng(txtReading)

    'Call the update form deligate
    'Visual Studio slightly changed this from the example on Microsoft's website that used a Windows Form
    'I tried the code in a windows form and I get the same results
    Me.Invoke(UpdateFormDeligate1) 'call the deligate
End Sub

Private Sub Invoke(updateFormDeligate1 As UpdateFormDeligate)
    lblResult.Label = sngReading 'set the Result label in the ribbon to equal the received data value

    'now place the data received in the active cell in the worksheet
    Dim myApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim currentCell = myApp.ActiveCell
    currentCell.Value = sngReading

    'advance cell to the next cell
    Dim newCell = currentCell
    newCell = myApp.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
    newCell.Select()
    currentCell = newCell

    'check if this was the first reading from the instrument
    'if it was the first reading, then send a second read command
    If measureNo = 1 Then
        measureNo = 2 'make sure to change measurement number to 2 to avoid infinite loop
        mySerialPort.Write(CMD) 'send command to measure to instrument
    End If
End Sub

'the usage of this section changed from the Microsoft Windows Form example
'in function, the mySerialPort_DataREceived(), Invoke(), and UpdateDisplay() functions do appear to be
'working with the same results and same hangups
Private Sub UpdateDisplay()

End Sub

Private Sub btnMeasure_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnMeasure.Click
    setupConnectCOM() 'connect to COM and send first measure command
End Sub
End Class
```